# HTTP Patch XmlHttpRequest support

Tags: jquery, node.js, browser, express

I am working on some todo app and would like to use the HTTP method PATCH to add and remove todo's because this would be semantically better than PUT.

In the backend I am using express.js (node.js) and in the front-end backbone.js (which uses jQuery for ajax).

I already tried if it actually works in back- and front-end on my local developement suite (Archlinux, Chromium 20, node.js 0.8, express 2.X) and it worked:

**app.js**

```
app.patch('/todo/:id', function(req, res){
    console.log('patch successfull');
}
```

**chromium web console**

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/messages/4ff13720f00e2e2c4b000006',
    type: 'PATCH',
    data: { body: 'that is a patched message' } 
});
```

The request was mentioned and also database actions where possible without exceptions.

I would now like to know how other browsers support the patch method. I looked with google but it is hard to find something because PATCH has multiple meanings...

Comment: "multiple meanings" including "browser patch", "eye patch", and "pirate patch". The first being the results that pop up most often. `:P`

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you `use` the `express.methodOverride()` middleware, you can send a param called `_method` with your `POST` requests, and Express will route it to the method in the param (for example `_method=patch` would execute `app.patch`).

Comment: Hi, I know, that is the only common way to sent PUTs and POST without Javascript. I just read in stackoverflow that XmlHttpRequests are independent from the http method patch but I am not sure about this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)

Answer (score 5):

Most browsers restrict HTTP methods to GET/POST when applied to forms. However, with AJAX requests as long as the backend server can support the method it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Modern browsers do support PATCH (in fact with $ajax you can do any method you like, as long as the browser doesn't block it). **Below IE9 you're out of luck.**

With FF, Chrome and Safari it's less of an issue, because those started auto-updating years ago and more than two years ago they stopped blocking methods other than GET and POST.