# HTTP PATCH support in browsers

Tags: rest, http-patch

I am designing REST endpoints for my application and i need to use PATCH for a few of the endpoints. Will all browsers that support HTTP/1.1 be able to support the PATCH ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

HTTP/1.1 did not define the `PATCH` method.

HTTP/1.1 does leave itself open for clients and/or servers to add new methods.

[RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) defined the conventions for using the [`PATCH`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_verb) method.

The method defined within a HTTP request is nothing more than a string. Browsers should allow JavaScript to use whatever HTTP method it wants in the `XmlHttpRequest`; see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288608/http-patch-xmlhttprequest-support) for more info. In short, any *modern* browser will allow you to do this, i.e. IE9+ and Firefox/Chrome/Safari/Opera/Spartan from the last few years.

Also, don't forget the server needs to specifically handle the `PATCH` method too, it doesn't just magically happen.

Comment: It seems that windows edge does not support patch.

Comment: It seems it does.