# Why are browsers unable to send http requests, other than GET and POST, natively?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, http, browser

Basically, the title says it all. I've encountered this issue while reading about http requests in [rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#cha-3_footnote-ref-5):

> The other two verbs, PATCH and DELETE, are designed for updating and
>   destroying things on the remote server. These requests are less common
>   than GET and POST since browsers are incapable of sending them
>   natively, but some web frameworks (including Ruby on Rails) have
>   clever ways of making it seem like browsers are issuing such requests.

Why is there a need to hack around to issue, for example, a `PATCH` request? Why aren't browsers able to natively perform such kind of things? Am I missing something? 
    I've been searching around for quite a while, but couldn't come up with a clear answer to these questions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257327/http-patch-support-in-browsers