# HTTP PATCH verb support status

Tags: google-chrome, http, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, http-patch

Which browsers support HTTP PATCH now, I've not found any *recent* information online. I'm especially interested to know if Chrome, Internet Explorer 11 and Microsoft Edge support the HTTP PATCH verb. I need this because I'm wondering if I should implement it in a RESTful API I'm working on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking which browsers are issuing `PATCH` requests by themselves, AFAIK [none do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257327/http-patch-support-in-browsers). However, virtually all javascript libraries I've encountered had the capability to send out requests with verbs other than `GET`, `HEAD`, and `POST`. In fact, all browsers compliant with [XmlHttpRequest Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20120117/#request-method) should allow `PATCH` to "slip through."