# Java - HttpServlet Patch method

Tags: java, servlets, http-patch

I'm implementing a REST Api using basic Servlets in Java and I can't seem to find a `doPatch()` method.

Why does [`HttpServlet`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) not implement a [`PATCH`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_verb) method? I'd like to use it 'cause it is more meaningful for resources update.

Comment: this should shed some light on the decision https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257327/http-patch-support-in-browsers

Comment: JSR 315 that defines servlet api 3.0 does not recognize patch method. so its not implemented.

Comment: @Ramanlfc will using a PUT instead be equally correct?

Comment: PUT should be used for completely replace a resource. PATCH for modifying just some of its properties.

Comment: @bluish in the end I resorted to POST, at that time. Note that I don't use the Servlet stack anymore when possible.